# Facebook c# sdk error OAuthException - #2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to publish a post on my Facebook page and I receive this error

> (OAuthException - #2) An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.

```
  FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);
      
      var result = app.Post("/" + model.pageId + "/feed", messagePost);
```

Comment: Which SDK do you use?

Comment: hello Nathaniel thank you for your question i am using facebook c# sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
            //messagePost.access_token="accesstoken";
            messagePost.picture = "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk16aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg";
            messagePost.link = "https://exemple.com/";
            //messagePost.name = model.titre;
            //messagePost.caption = "this post was created by my website";
            messagePost.message = "test_message";


FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);
      
      var result = app.Post("/" + model.pageId + "/feed", messagePost);
```

the problem was i give facebook the access token 2 times and that confuses facebook api
i just removed messagePost.access_token and it works fine